# Longest Common Subsequence C (Python Script explanation)

Tags: python, c, dynamic-programming, lcs

i have been working for the last few days on a Longest Common Subsequence program, in C, using dynamic programming. Though, I have a memory issue as i am trying to process a lot of data (and i mean A LOT) which result to memory overflow.

Fortunately i have found a linear space complexity algorithm which can be useful not getting memory overflow, but is written in Python. Can someone help me understand what is going on in the picture below?

[image: Python Script for LCS Distance]

More specific i don t understand what it going on in line "curr = list(itertools.repeat(0, 1 + ny))"

For the rest i can guess.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This does not need an image of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it works:

1. Read length of ys by the code `my=len(ys)` which will be 10 in the "Chimpanzee" example
2. your itertools.repeat will be `list(itertools.repeat(1,11))` will give you a list with 1 eleven times

   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

And as you said rest you have figured it out.

For more info on repeat check this out:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html